# How to make code folding work from the margin?

Tags: xcode

I'd like to use code folding as shown here: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/recipes/xcode_help-source_editor/chapters/CodeFolding.html.

In the 2nd image, you can see in the left margin the down arrow, meaning code is unfolded.  That will appear for every function. I don't have that in my margin. I'm using Xcode 7.3.1.

If you use any of the menu items in the Editor menu, it's the big hammer approach and doesn't allow you to fold/unfold individual functions.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the Preferences > Text Editing > Editing > Code folding ribbon checkbox.